# The ndb_mgmd daemon does not start

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

The ndb_mgmd daemon does not start

I want to configure a NDB Mysql cluster, I followed the documentation of its official page. Install version 7.5 of mysql-cluster-community and I have the following scheme

1 manager node: 192.168.10.137

2 nodes mysqld: 192.168.10.140,192.168.10.139

2 nodes of data: 192.168.10.138,192.168.10.141

This is the configuration file of the manager, my config.ini;

```
[ndbd default]
# Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
NoOfReplicas = 2 # Number of replicas
DataMemory = 80M # How much memory to allocate for data storage
IndexMemory = 18M # How much memory to allocate for index storage
                  # For DataMemory and IndexMemory, we have used the
                  # default values. Since the "world" database takes up
                  # only about 500KB, this should be more than enough for
                  # this example NDB Cluster setup.
ServerPort = 1186 # This the default value; however, you can use any
                  # port that is free for all hosts in the cluster
                  # Note1: It is recommended that you do not specify the port
                  # number at all and simply allow the default value to be used
                  # instead
                  # Note2: The port was formerly specified using the PortNumber
                  # TCP parameter; this parameter is no longer available in NDB
                  # Cluster 7.5.

[ndb_mgmd]
# Management process options:
HostName = 192.168.10.137 # Hostname or IP address of MGM node
DataDir = / var / lib / mysql-cluster # Directory for MGM node log files
NodeId = 1

[ndbd]
# Configuration for the data node with ip 139
                                                        # (one [ndbd] section per data node)
HostName = 192.168.10.139 # Hostname or IP address
NodeId = 2 # Node ID for this data node
DataDir = / usr / local / mysql / data # Directory for this data node's data files

[ndbd]
# Configuration for the data node with ip 140
HostName = 192.168.10.140 # Hostname or IP address
NodeId = 3 # Node ID for this data node
DataDir = / usr / local / mysql / data # Directory for this data node's data files

[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
HostName = 192.168.10.138 # Hostname or IP address
                                                  
[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
HostName = 192.168.10.141 # Hostname or IP address
```

This is the configuration file of the nodes:

```
[mysqld]
# Options for mysqld process:
ndbcluster # run NDB storage engine
```

[mysql_cluster]

```
# Options for NDB Cluster processes:
ndb-connectstring = 192.168.10.137 # location of management server
```

When I try to tell mysql what the configuration file is, it tells me the following:

```
root @ mysql: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d# ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
bash: ndb_mgmd: Order not found
```

But if I use the command "ndb_mgm" if I enter this part:

```
- NDB Cluster - Management Client -
ndb_mgm>
```

And if from there I indicate the order:

```
-f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
```

It tells me the following:

```
Unable to connect with connect string: nodeid = 0, localhost: 1186
```

I tried to start the ndb_mgm from the folder where the config.ini file is but I can not execute it.Sorry for my english.